# Nest Sample iOS (iOS-NestDK) Application

Tags: nest-api

I'm stuck and hopefully someone who has gone through this can help me.  I've gone through the sample iOS application provided by Nest.  I have registered as a developer and have a nest client ID and nest client secret.  I have downloaded the sample application and my goal is to use this a reference to build an iOS application that interfaces with multiple connected devices within my home.

I have compiled the application and can run this through xCODE.  Using the client ID, and client secret key, I'm also able to go to the Client Authorization screen.  I then can login to nest, and get a PIN.  This is where I'm stuck, I was expecting that by authorizing the client I would somehow get an access token that I can use during the API calls to provide access.  I see the sample code to parse for the access token, but I don't see any code path to get to retrieving and access token.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I just found the answer I was looking for.  I was missing the redirect URI and after setting this up in the application I can now get through.  My application is really not posting to a server and therefore assumed I did not need a redirect URI.  Apparently this is required by next but there is a workaround for iOS and Osx...  Here's the thread.

[Non-HTTP[S] OAuth redirect for Nest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171830/non-https-oauth-redirect-for-nest-api)

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at this too but found the solution in Android-nestdk 
"The OAUTH REDIRECT_URL is to be set in the client registration page on the nest developer website and NOT ONLY in Constants.m"

```
I also put https://localhost on both location and it worked immediately like the user said.
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27530025/954074